# Worklight Adapter Basic Authentication Caching?

Tags: javascript, json, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm having an issue with basic authentication using a Worklight adapter. Whenever I authenticate to a REST URL, it authenticates fine. However, the authentication seems to create a session within the Worklight server.

**Example Call**

```
function getTaskList(username,password) {

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'rest/url',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic '+base64Encode(username+':'+password),
        }   
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Whenver I attempt  to login from another device, Worklight server thinks I'm already signed in. Can you turn off session support in Worklight server or prevent caching? I want to authenticate every time to the REST URL. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>in the `<procedure>` element of the adapter XML file you should add `connectAs="endUser"`. The connection to the back end will be created with the user's identity.</strike>

I am sorry, I did not understand your question.
In order to  authenticate every time what you need to do is in the `connectionPolicy` in the adapter XML file you need to change your `cookiePolicy` Attribute to `IGNORE_COOKIES`

```
<connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType" cookiePolicy="IGNORE_COOKIES" maxRedirects="int"></connectionPolicy>
```

Comment: This does not work. Worklight Server is storing a JSESSIONID for the first user. When another getTaskList('user2','password2') is issued, Worklight Server still returns back tasks (in JSON) from the original user. The adapter was redeployed in Worklight Studio just to make sure. All calls originate from RunAs->Worklight Procdure.