# Worklight Server 6.1 Session Control by User

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security

I've implemented Login Module, e i would not allow the same User on different devices connect to the same time.I thought of two solutions. 
1 - If the User is an active session with the device"A" and connect the "B" device, forcing the device "A" to authenticate again. 
2 - If the User is an active session with the device "A" block access to any other device with the same User.

To get the expected result, I need to control the users manually,

```
List<User> leggedUsers = new ArrayList<>(); ...
```

or worklight provides some way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the following fully answers your question, but it **may** be one possible solution. See the answer to this question: [Worklight Adapter Basic Authentication Caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838087/worklight-adapter-basic-authentication-caching)